# Azure group claim returns Object ID - Need group name

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Have been using Azure for Single Sign On.

For group claims, during the assertion we see only the security group object ID during the response.

e4feedb1-df0e-46ff-8a02-e63474015610

Is it possible to get Group name here in response instead of groups Object ID

Comment: If any answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

If (and only if) the groups in question are groups which have been synced from on-premises AD, you can configure the groups claim to include the on-premises `sAMAccountName` or the on-premises SID.

> **Note**: Including the display name is not supported. (Display names are not unique, and in most organization, any user is able to create and manage their own groups, making any sort of authorization decision based on group display names a very risky proposition.)

To issue group can be done both for gallery or non-gallery (i.e. custom) SAML apps (i.e. under Enteprise apps), through the app registration in the Azure portal (App registrations > Token configuration), or directly on the app registration's `Application` object by updating the `optionalClaims` property (e.g. via the manifest editor or through Microsoft Graph).

- https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims

[image: Editing groups claim from the Azure portal]

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid that it's only supported to get the object ids currently.

You need to call Microsoft Graph to get the Group name.

If you do need this feature, [upvote this post on UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/38483242-option-to-show-group-name-in-groups-claims) and it may be implemented in the future.

A similar question which is answered by Microsoft Engineer [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/38625).